# vrpn_client_ros Unable to Locate Package

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, mocap-optitrack, optitrack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm pretty new to ROS and linux, so my questions may seem pretty basic, sorry. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and ROS Melodic.
I am currently following [this](https://mzahana.gitbooks.io/indoor-nav-at-risclab/content/motion-capture-setup-and-wifi-communications.html) tutorial to install [vrpn_client_ros](https://github.com/ros-drivers/vrpn_client_ros).

I entered the below command in the terminal, and the response I get is below that.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-vrpn-client-ros -y

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-vrpn-client-ros
```

Now I have two questions:

1. Are programs built for older distributions of ROS able to be installed/run on newer distributions of ROS? If not, that would explain why it's unable to locate the package.
2. According to the GitHub [here](https://github.com/ros-drivers-gbp/vrpn_client_ros-release), it seems like a newer version of the package has been updated for Melodic. However, I'm not sure if it's available for people to install yet. Would anyone possibly be able to give some insight?

Thank you very much in advance! Being new to ROS, linux, and GitHub, there's been a lot to take in.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297054/vrpn_client_ros-unable-to-locate-package/) by [astemeric](https://answers.ros.org/users/36387/astemeric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2018-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can't install install Kinetic packages using `apt` while using Ubuntu 18.04 as they require 16.04. You can try cloning it into your workspace and compiling it yourself.

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src
git clone -b kinetic-devel https://github.com/ros-drivers/vrpn_client_ros.git
cd ..
catkin_make
source devel/setup.bash
```

I used the `kinetic-devel` branch as it appears to be the latest one.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [astemeric](https://answers.ros.org/users/36387/astemeric/) on 2018-07-12**:
That worked perfectly. Thank you!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-12**:
No problem. Could you please click on the check mark to mark the answer as correct?